# Necessisty of Comparable interface

Tags: java, interface, casting, comparable

Comparable interface contains only one method `compareTo(T o)`and for example `Collections.sort()` method first type-cast the compared object to `Comparable` and then compares it.

Now I am unable to understand why we need this process in the first place. Wouldn't it be just simpler to call directly `compareTo()` method of the object and get rid of the `Comparable` interface? If the object doesn't have `compareTo()` method it would raise an error anyway just like it does if the object didn't implement `Comparable` interface.

Besides I don't see a reason one would need a `Comparable` type object. Is there any advantages of having a `Comparable` interface ?

Comment: What guarantee do you have that the object even *has* a `compareTo()` method, if it doesn't implement the Comparable interface?

Comment: Are you suggesting that `Object` should include the `compareTo` method? If so, how would you compare, say, a database to a database?

Comment: The idea is to detect problems at compile time, rather than run time. Collections.sort will only ever throw a ClassCastException at run time if you’ve abused generics in some way (e.g used raw types)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `Comparable` isn't *necessary*: you could do everything with a compatible instance of `Comparator` instead. `Comparable` is for classes which have a notion of *natural* ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only calling `compareTo` *yourself,* then it's true that there's no particular reason to implement `Comparable`.

But for things like `Collections.sort` and `TreeSet`, those aren't hardcoded for a specific type, but they have to be able to call `compareTo` on the objects you pass it to.  That's what the `Comparable` interface is before: implementing `Comparable` means that `Collections.sort` and `TreeSet` know that the objects you pass them will *have* that method to be called.  Implementing `Comparable` means you can use all of the utilities that exist that need to order objects in any way, and those utilities know how to interact with your objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides I don't see a reason one would need a Comparable type object.
>   Is there any advantages of having a Comparable interface ?

How do you want that `Object`  implement `compareTo()` ?
Giving a default implement in makes no sense.
Besides, increasing the responsibility of `Object` class for a requirement very specific is not a good idea either.
At last, all `Object` subclasses are not necessary "`Comparable`" either.
So how to implement it for them ? With an `UnsupportedOperationException` for example ?
It definitively would make things less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, without a `Comparable` interface stating that the `compareTo()` method exists and is publicly invokable, the JVM would have to resort to using reflection to discover it, which would be *very* costly . For example, the JVM wouldn't be able to inline calls to the method.
The interface is thus of utmost importance for the compiler (type-checking) and for the runtime performance.

Furthermore, the interface is a strong indication that the `compareTo()` method was implemented *on purpose* to compare instances of that class, and not just a method that *happened* to have that exact signature but was doing something entirely different.

Finally, the `Comparable` interface marks the classes that implement it as having a "natural comparison order" (like numbers, dates...), as opposed to objects that can have equally-important orderings (eg. a Person : by age, size, first name...). 
So it is also an important information in terms of class design.